# yii2 RestAPI modelClass value for model from other app

Tags: rest, yii2

I am developing a RESTful API looking at the documentation from http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-rest-versioning.html and http://budiirawan.com/setup-restful-api-yii2/.
I have a model (ActiveRecord) class called `Client` in `common/models` folder as

```
namespace common\models;

class Client extends ActiveRecord
{
  ...
}
```

Then, I have `ClientController` class in `api/modules/v1/controllers` folder as

```
namespace api\modules\v1\controllers;

class ClientController extends ActiveController {

    public $modelClass = 'common\models\Client';
}
```

If I browse ***localhost/api/v1/clients*** I get "***Class common\models\Client not found***" error. I tried different versions of modelClass, but cannot get the answer.
Maybe I need to configure something extra? Any help is appreciated, thanks

Comment: Are your namespaces correctly configured in the application? Does `new \common\models\Client();` work for example? Best to make sure al the rest works as well.

Comment: How did you solve it anyway? Having the same issue.

Comment: I put `public $modelClass = '\\common\models\Client';` and it works now.

Comment: @spargapis Wrong, You call client with ``pluralize`` with 's', you can set ``pluralize`` to false, never need to change ``$modelClass``.